# Insert css rule with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to change my div background from time of the day with this code,but doesn't working.I want to add it to my embed css(fourth link). It will add to the remaining rule.

```
var hur = new Date();
    var dyng = hur.getHours()
   if(dyng > 6 && dyng < 18){
     document.styleSheets[3].cssRules[0].style.background="url('/blog/themes/custom/img/sky.jpg')"
   }else{
    document.styleSheets[3].cssRules[0].style.background="url('/blog/themes/custom/img/night.jpg')"
   }
```

css

```
#test {
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
}
```

Comment: You can use jQuery to add css rules `$("#test").css({'background':'image.jpg'}));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically can be achieved in a simple way by using a pair of jQuery methods:

```
.addClass()
.removeClass()
```

In a plain Javascript solution the same can be done with a pair of functions:

```
element.setAttribute ("class", "CSS class name");
element.removeAttribute ("class", "CSS class name");
```

Comment: Or in plain JavaScript with the `className` property.

Comment: Please stop using jQuery solutions to plain javascript questions.

Comment: You will need to explain more than this, because he is probably going to need to removeClass as well to.

Comment: @Axel no! Jquery jquery jquery!

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript to modify CSS is not a good idea.

It's better to have all your styles defined in CSS and have JavaScript select *which* of those rules gets applying by adding/removing classes.

You can use the `.className` property for DOM Elements (but I would recommend using a framework).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) function.

```
element.setAttribute('class', 'class name');
```